# Symfony REST DTO validation and inject in Model like paramconverter

Tags: json, rest, symfony

I want to create a request filter for post actions in a json rest api that takes the request's body and fill the DTO, validate it and inject it in the controller action like paramconverter.

How can I do that?

I have a DTO like this:

```
class ExampleDTO
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @NotNull(message="El campo nombre es requerido")
     * @Type(name="string", message="El campo nombre tiene un tipo incorrecto")
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNombre()
    {
        return $this->nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $nombre
     */
    public function setNombre($nombre)
    {
        $this->nombre = $nombre;
    }


}
```

Now I want to transform the json to this DTO and inject it into controller.

Comment: Your question has several parts and it's not clear to me which part you are asking about.  The documentation shows how to plug in your own param converter: http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#creating-a-converter

Comment: Take request body, convert it to a object, and use it in the controller.

Answer (score 2):

Actually ParamConverter works with route params (like as {id} in "/myapp.com/post/{id}"), not with request body.

If you use FOSRestBundle, Request Body Converter Listener (http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/request_body_converter_listener.html) is available.

Simple example from FOSRestBundle docs:

```
/**
 * @ParamConverter("dto", converter="fos_rest.request_body", options={"validator"={"groups"={"foo", "bar"}}})
 */
public function putAction(ExampleDTO $exampleDTO, ConstraintViolationListInterface $validationErrors)
{
    if (count($validationErrors) > 0) {
        // Handle validation errors
    }

    // ...
}
```

Also you should adjust your app confiuration for this approach this way:

```
# app/config/config.yml
sensio_framework_extra:
    request: { converters: true }


# app/config/config.yml
fos_rest:
    body_converter:
        enabled: true
```